# jQuery-ui draggable and resizable div can't resize from the left properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am trying to make a resizable and draggable div that is at a fixed position.
The div looks fine when I resize it from the right or bottom; however, when I resize it from the left or top, the draggable div seems to increase height/weight in the opposite position.

Here is the code:
HTML

```
<div id="draggableDiv" >
  <div id="resizableDiv">
    <div id="content"><div id="contentTitle"></div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
 $('#draggableDiv').draggable({
    handle: '#contentTitle'
  });
  $("#resizableDiv").resizable({
    handles: 'n, e, s, w, ne, se, sw, nw'
  });
```

CSS:

```
  #draggableDiv {
     position:fixed !important;
     width:auto;
     height:auto;
     left:100px;
     top: 100px;
   }

   #resizableDiv {
     height: 200px;
     width: 200px;
   }

   #content { height:100%; width:100%; }
```

What should I do to make the draggable div resizes itself correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the outer container `#draggableDiv` resizable. If you do that, then it is also required to modify your css a bit to set this div the desired dimensions. For example,

http://jsfiddle.net/RkNT4/

**html**

```
<div id="draggableDiv">
    <div id="resizableDiv">
        <div id="content">
            <div id="contentTitle">content title</div>
            conteeeeeent
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**js**

```
$('#draggableDiv').draggable({
    handle: '#contentTitle'
});
$("#draggableDiv").resizable({
    handles: 'n, e, s, w, ne, se, sw, nw'
});
```

**css**

```
/*colors were added for the example to separate each div*/
    #draggableDiv {
        position:fixed !important;
        width:auto;
        height:auto;
        left:100px;
        top: 100px;
        background-color:green;
        height:200px;
        width:200px;
    }
    #contentTitle{
        background-color:red;
        cursor:move;
    }
    #resizableDiv {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
    #content {
        height:100%;
        width:100%;
        background-color:blue;
    }
```

Comment: I tried that before and it didn't work. However, it magically works now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can apply the jquery draggable & resizable to the parent container, this works fine.

```
$('#draggableDiv').draggable({
   handle: '#contentTitle'
}).resizable({
   handles: 'n, e, s, w, ne, se, sw, nw'
});
```

BTW I did a Jsfiddle where you can check that
http://jsfiddle.net/kQtMF/